# How to change the z value to the one from the table (Z-Table from Normal Distribution) in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, statistics, probability, normal-distribution

i have task to make a program using C++ to calculate a probability using a normal distribution. If i already found the Z value, how to change it to become the one from the Z table? Like -0.55, in the z-table is 0.29116. And 0.85 in the table is 0.80234.

Because what i know array is only know what column and row to display.
Thanks.

[image: Z Table]

Comment: If you have a formula for calculating the probability from the z-value, then you should probably focus on implementing that formula, and just forget the table (after all, the table was made from the formula to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is for the [Cumulative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) [Normal Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). This is easiest to implement using the [`erfc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/erfc/) standard library math function:

```cpp
double cumulativeNormal(double x) {
    return 0.5 * std::erfc(-x * M_SQRT1_2);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << cumulativeNormal(-0.55) << '\n';  // prints 0.29116
}
```

Comment: I dont need to change it? So the formulas is return 0.5 * std::erfc(-x) * M_SQRT1_2 ?

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word "change".

Given the value `z = -0.55`, instead of looking it up in the table you can calculate it using the function above.

Comment: M_SQRT1_2 was not declared. Why is this?

Comment: M_SQRT1_2  is declared in the <math.h> header.

Comment: How to use a standard library math function in Gamma Table? For example Fg(8;8), in the table is 0.5470. And Fg(4;8) in the table is 0.0511. [GAMMA TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgBX.jpg)

Comment: Please put that in a new question and I will try to answer.